# invalid old size from function

Tags: c, input, realloc

So I have the function

```
void getInput(char* input) {
        char buffer[BUFF_SIZE];
        char *buff = buffer;
        size_t buffersize = 32;
        getline(&buff, &buffersize, stdin);
        buffer[strlen(buffer) - 1] = '\0';
        strcpy(input, buffer);
}
```

and this function is passed a variable with the declaration of `char input[BUFF_SIZE]` and BUFF_SIZE is defined as `#define BUFF_SIZE 5000`

anyways the error I am having is that when I debug it in gdb I get the error
`Error in './dash': realloc(): invalid old size: 0x00007ffdf5a6fab0 ***`

the upon using where I then get this information

```
#0  0x00002aaaaad05387 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00002aaaaad06a78 in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00002aaaaad47ed7 in __libc_message () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#3  0x00002aaaaad4e3e4 in malloc_printerr () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#4  0x00002aaaaad537d1 in _int_realloc () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#5  0x00002aaaaad55c52 in realloc_hook_ini () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#6  0x00002aaaaad3e96b in getdelim () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#7  0x0000000000400f05 in getInput (input=0x7fffffffbae0 "") at dash.c:104
#8  0x0000000000400bbe in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe308) at dash.c:50
```

I am completely lost at this point and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are using `strlen` to decide where to add a null terminator to your string. But `strlen` works by looking for a null terminator, so that line won't work. Just use `buffer[buffersize-1] = '\0';`

Comment: When/where does gdb give you that error? Also, that stack trace refers to line 104 in your code - which is line 104?

Comment: actually `buffer[strlen(buffer) - 1] = '\0'` has no effect... unless the string is empty in whic case it's UB.

Comment: problem is that `getline(&buff, &buffersize, stdin);` will try to free `buff`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre it actually has . Except the empty string (UB) it shortens the string by 1 char.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre https://godbolt.org/z/8n9nnd

Comment: you're right. It's needed to remove the last `\n`... if it's there...

Answer (score 4):

The pointer (to pointer) argument to `getline()` must be passable to `free()`.  The POSIX specification for [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) says:

> The application shall ensure that `*lineptr` is a valid argument that could be passed to the `free()` function. If `*n` is non-zero, the application shall ensure that `*lineptr` either points to an object of size at least `*n` bytes, or is a null pointer.

You are violating that restriction because the local variable `buffer` cannot be passed to `free()`.  All hell can break loose — especially as you also lie about the size of the buffer, claiming it is only 32 bytes long when it is actually 5000 bytes long (so that reallocation will be necessary for quite short input lines).

Read the specification — follow the rules it lays down.

The `getInput()` function also has no idea about the size of the buffer pointed to by the `input` argument to the function, but it does an unconditional copy of everything read into the `input` buffer.  That is a recipe for buffer overflow.  Your `getInput()` function needs a different signature and should be more like:

```
ssize_t getInput(size_t in_len, char input[in_len])
{
    char *buffer = NULL;
    size_t *buflen = 0;
    ssize_t nbytes;
    if ((nbytes = getline(&buffer, &buflen, stdin)) == -1)
    {
        free(buffer);  // Free any space allocated by getline()
        return EOF;
    }
    if (buffer[nbytes - 1] == '\n'). /* Zap newline if present */
        buffer[--nbytes] = '\0';
    if ((size_t)nbytes >= in_len)
    {
        free(buffer);  // Release space allocated by getline()
        *input = '\0';
        return 0;   // Or another value to indicate an error
    }
    strcpy(input, buffer);
    free(buffer);
    return nbytes;
}
```

That will tell you how many bytes are in the input buffer, avoiding overflows.  It does make a copy of the data, just as your original function does — presumably, that is OK to you.

Note that `getline()` returns `-1` and not `EOF` (though the two are usually the same).  It can (and usually does) allocate space for a NULL buffer pointer before detecting EOF, so it is necessary to free the buffer it allocates even when there is no data.  A valid implementation of `getline()` never returns `0` — it returns `-1` or a strictly positive value.

Comment: lying about the size is the issue. Passing 5000 as the size would mask the bug in most cases since realloc wouldn't be called unless a file has a very long line. That would create an even more sneaky bug.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre — yes, the fib about the size of the buffer makes it far more likely that the problem will be revealed.  That's a blessing.  I decided not to elaborate on that since the prerequisite condition about the buffer not being passable to `free()` makes the use undefined behaviour.  I've also added notes about avoiding buffer overflows, etc.  The original design of the function leaves quite a lot to be desired.

Comment: I think OP is trying to remove the last linefeed with `buffer[strlen(buffer) - 1] = '\0';`, which can be a problem if last line doesn't end with newline (but you know that!). Your code doesn't seem to do that (`strcspn` would do the job better IIRC)

Comment: There is no lie about the size. The documentation says “If *n is non-zero, the application shall ensure that *lineptr either points to an object of size at least *n bytes, or is a null pointer.” 5000 bytes is at least 32 bytes.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre — yes, you're probably right.  That can be done, too.  I'll update.

Comment: @EricPostpischil — there is a lie about the size (the buffer is 5000 bytes, not 32 bytes).  However, you can argue that saying 32 is "safe", and it would be if the pointer was dynamically allocated (could be passed to `free()`).  When the buffer can't be passed to `free()`, if the input exceeds the stated (not actual) size of the buffer, then `getline()` will attempt to allocate more space and free the space passed to it, wreaking havoc on the memory allocation system.  Now the lie hurts.

Comment: @user3121023 — yes; the leak will be fixed momentarily.  The advantage of this over `fgets()` is the removed newline (see previous edit).  It also reports the length of the line which `fgets()` does not — it can be used on data containing null bytes which `fgets()` can't usefully be used on.  There are quite a lot of gotchas available w.r.t null bytes even so.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: It is not a lie. The specification for `getline` implies the caller asserts the buffer is at least `*n` bytes. For the code in the question, that is a true assertion. You can explain the code is inefficient and/or is not using `getline` in the way intended, but a “lie” is an intentionally false statement, and this is not one. As lying has moral implications, you should not falsely accuse a person of lying.

Comment: @EricPostpischil — Clearly, we have different interpretations of whether it is a lie. I can see your point but I still regard stating that a 5000-byte buffer is only 32-bytes long as a lie, albeit one which in many circumstances would be mostly harmless. You may prefer alternative wording; that's your prerogative. I regard my wording as valid, and it's my answer so it stays.

Comment: It is not a matter of opinion whether the assertion implied by the call is true. It is true. The documented precondition for the call is that the allocated memory be at least `*n` bytes. It is; that is a fact and is not in dispute. There is no precondition that the allocated memory not be more than `*n` bytes. Making the call does not constitute a statement that the buffer is only `*n` bytes long, and therefore there is no false statement and can be no lie.

Answer (score 2):

the problem is that you cannot pass a buffer that hasn't been allocated with `malloc` in the first place to `getline`:

> Alternatively, before calling [getline()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline), *lineptr can contain a pointer to a malloc(3)-allocated buffer *n bytes in size. **If the buffer is not large enough to hold the line, getline() resizes it with realloc(3), updating *lineptr and *n as necessary.**

`getline` sees the buffer as not big enough since the passed size is 32 so it proceeds to `realloc` and it fails, because when the system calls `realloc` on your non-(m)allocated `buffer` it invokes undefined behaviour (and probably crashes your app).

The bug would have been hidden if `size_t buffersize = 5000;` was set, since `getline` wouldn't have to realloc the buffer (but it would still be bad if a line is bigger than 5000 chars, so it's still a bug)

So you have to set `buffer` to `NULL` and let `getline` allocate it for you.

```
char *buff = NULL;
size_t buffersize = 0;
```

In the very end, deallocate with `free(buffer)`

Comment: the size must be zero too.

Comment: Well it doesn't matter: from the manual: _If *lineptr is NULL, then getline() will allocate a buffer for storing the line, which should be freed by the user program. (In this case, the value in *n is ignored.)_

Comment: Hmm, POSIX spec says *or*, Linux man pages say *and* :D